# How do I save an image in python 3 using PIL?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL in python 3 in a program that recolours an image. What it does is, it permanently loops through the pixel values of `file.gif` (which are returned as integers) and then adds 10 to each of them. I then want it to save the file, which can then be reopened to write to a tkinter label (I've got the rest, but I just need to know about the saving).

Using this code, I have got the program to open the image and display it in the window, then modify the pixel values, but it doesn't change the image displayed.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time, sys

def col():
    global count1,count,pix,x,root
    count1+=1
    print("("+str(count1)+")")
    count=-1
    for i in pix:
        count+=1
        #print(i)
        i+=10
        pix[count]=i

    photo = PhotoImage(file="AI.gif")
    x.configure(image=photo)
    root.update()
    root.after(100, col)

root=Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file="AI.gif")
x=Label(root, compound="top", image=photo)
x.pack(side="right")

img = Image.open("AI.gif")
pix=list(img.getdata())
width=img.size[0]
height=img.size[1]
img.close()

root.geometry((str(width)+"x"+str(height))+"-0+0")
root.update()

count1=0
col()

root.mainloop()
```

I am using this image currently:
[image]

**Edit:**
@Tadhg McDonald-Jensen
I've just run the program with all your suggested edits, but have got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\recolour1.py", line 47, in <module>
    col()
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\recolour1.py", line 19, in col
    photo.paste(img)
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'paste'
```

**Edit2:**
here is my latest version of the code that doesn't seem to be modifying the image in the tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time, sys

def col():
    global count1,count,pix,x,root,photo
    img = Image.open("AI.gif").convert("RGB")
    pix=list(img.getdata())
    count1+=1
    print("("+str(count1)+")")
    count=-1
    for i in pix:
        count+=1
        #print(i)
        i = tuple(V+100 for V in i)

    img.putdata(pix)
    photo.paste(img)
    root.update()
    img.close()
    root.after(10, col)

root=Tk()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="AI.gif")
x=Label(root, compound="top", image=photo)
x.pack(side="right")
img = Image.open("AI.gif").convert("RGB")
width,height=img.size[0],img.size[1]
img.close()
root.geometry((str(width)+"x"+str(height))+"-0+0")
root.update()
count1=0
col()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why aren't you using `ImageTk.PhotoImage`?

Comment: How would I do that? I forgot to mention that I am still relatively new to tkinter

Comment: you never have to label yourself as new (your rep does help imply it) I'll happily post an answer...

Comment: you need to use `ImageTk.PhotoImage`,  replace the line `photo = PhotoImage("AI.gif")` with `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage("AI.gif")`

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen I've tried all your suggestions and edits, but now it seems not to be updating the image again, it's doing everything else I want it to, just not that. I've posted the latest code above.

Comment: oh sorry, you replaced `i+=10` with the tuple assignment but you still have to do `pix[count] = i`. I edited my answer with code suggestions, I have a feeling we probably want to continue discussion in chat if you have further inquiries.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, I probably should have thought to look for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every time you do:

```
PhotoImage(file="AI.gif")
```

you are loading the file again, note that the file never changes throughout this process hence the image never changes.  if you have loaded the image with PIL then you can use `ImageTk.PhotoImage` to load the data from the image:

```
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

(be sure to do this *after* defining `img`) 
then you never need to re-open the image with this:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="AI.gif")
x.configure(image=photo)
```

Instead you just need to put the new pixel data into img, then update `photo` with the new data in `img` with:

```
img.putdata(pix)
photo.paste(img)
```

EDIT: just to clarify here is your code with all my suggested edits:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time, sys


def col():
    global count1,count,pix,x,root,img
    count1+=1
    print("("+str(count1)+")")
    count=-1
    for i in pix:
        count+=1
        #print(i)
        i+=10
        pix[count]=i

    #update the data in img and then paste it into photo
    img.putdata(pix)
    photo.paste(img)
    root.update()
    root.after(100, col)

root=Tk()

#load the image before making PhotoImage
img = Image.open("AI.gif")
pix=list(img.getdata())
width=img.size[0]
height=img.size[1]
#img.close() #don't close the image as you won't be able to modify it after closing

# do this part after defining img
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        # ^ use PIL's PhotoImage to use PIL operations on it
x=Label(root, compound="top", image=photo)
x.pack(side="right")

root.geometry((str(width)+"x"+str(height))+"-0+0")
root.update()

count1=0
col()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'd also like to mention that because the image is a `gif` increasing the pixel value by 10 is very likely not what you had in mind, you might need to convert it to RGB and modify that data instead.

Comment: How would I do that? I know it does it automatically for `.jpg` files, but I didn't realise you could do it for gifs as well

Comment: `img = Image.open("AI.gif")`[`.convert("RGB")`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)

Comment: then instead of just doing `i+=10` you could do `i = tuple(V +10 for V in i)` to add 10 to each Red, Green and Blue value

Comment: Thanks, I've just been using a previous version of this program (that didn't work) designed to run with a gif, and wrote a really long program to modify the tuple, this should really help!

Comment: hmm... with a RGB image it lags really badly on my computer... I'm looking into a more efficient way to gradually fade the image to white if you are interested.

Comment: What i'm using this for, is as a module for a larger program which displays an image in the top right corner of the screen, and then cycles through all the colours, so a modified version of that may be useful